# gcd from 2 factorisation lists using counters python

Tags: python, counter, greatest-common-divisor

I need to get the greatest common divisor of 2 numbers using their  factorizations
the factorizations will be put in counters

```
c=Counter(factorslist(a))
d=Counter(factorslist(b))
```

So I want to add the lists together like

```
g=c and d
```

and then my multiplying whats inside the counter by each other i should be able to get the gcd so if g is (2,2,3,8) i want it to calculate `2*2*3*8`.

I'm having a lot of trouble, is there already a counter function that does this? or do i need a loop to systematicaly times each number together? do i need to convert it to sets or something first?

UPDATE: alright so what ive done is added them together using g=c&d
woks fine
now im trying to get my algorithm working
    sol=1
    for i in range(maxg+1):
        if g[i]!=0:
         k=g[i]
         sol=sol*(i*k)
    return sol
so im checking how many of each number are in the common factors list of g and multiplying the number by the number of them and then multiplying sol by that eg five two's is sol=sol*(5*2). this seems to work with numbers with low gcds about 30 and less i think? and it works for coprimes, but if i run this with say 1000,500 i get 60 back... even tho 1000 and 990 gives me 10 back.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you've misunderstood a couple of things:
(1) The factorization is into primes -- 8 would be factored into 2*2*2
(2) Counter is not a list; it's a dictionary.  The list [2, 2, 3, 7] would be the counter object {2:2, 3:1, 7:1}

Thus, what you need is the "min" function on the counts of the common factors.  Then you need to multiply things in a resulting loop.

Can you take it from there?  See what you can work through; post again with your progress if you get stuck.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html has the available methods for Counter, as well as other classes with similar age and purpose.

Comment: I'm still struggling so i need to add "g=min(c and d)"? then how do i multiply things? this just ends up giving me the lowest common divisor so like "2" and thats it.

Comment: Start a running product, such as gcd = 1
You need to iterate through the elements of one counter (say, 'c').  For each element, see whether the key exists in 'd'.  If not, go to the next element.  If it does, take the min of the two values.

Now, loop 'min' times.  Each time, multiply gcd by the element key.  For instance, if you found elements 3:4 in c and 3:2 in d, you would iterate 2 times, multiplying by 3.

Comment: Excellent! Please remember to "accept" the answer, then, so the StackOverflow software properly resolves your question.